# Adding an event listener to the content of *ngTemplateOutlet or ng-template

Tags: angular

I need to add an event listener to either the content of a `ng-template` or `*ngTemplateOutlet` without knowing what the content might be. It could be a button or some custom component.

I tried accessing the `elementRef` but that is not working as it is a comment node.

When I add the `TemplateRef` via `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView`, I can't find any access to the element reference of the added view.

The other way I tried was getting accessing it via `@ViewChild("foo")` in my component and using a template outlet. No success.

`<ng-container #foo *ngTemplateOutlet="foo"></ng-container>`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I have a component and I want consumers to optionally provide some children in the same manner the [Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) handles custom icons.

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
    <custom-icon>edit</custom-icon>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
    <custom-icon>done</custom-icon>
  </ng-template>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Looking at this example, I need access to the `<custom-icon>` and add event handlers to it, without actually knowing that it is a `<custom-icon>`.

Comment: Do you want to add event listener to Comment node? Can you show us an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
export class SomethingWithTemplateComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('wrapperContentTemplate') wrapperContentTemplate: ElementRef;
    
    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.listen(this.wrapperContentTemplate?.nativeElement?.children[0], 'click', (event) => {
            // Do things when clicking on first element from #contentTemplate, e.g.: the <span>
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<ng-template #contentTemplate>
    <span>I'm in a template</span>
</ng-template>
<span #wrapperContentTemplate>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTemplate"></ng-container>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a attribute directive and add @HostListener to it. Here is an example

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, HostListener, HostBinding, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighLight]'
})
export class HighLightDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() defaultColor: string ='transparent';
  @Input() highLightColor: string ='blue';
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroundColor: string;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(){      
      this.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor;     
    }

    @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseIn(eventData : Event){      
      this.backgroundColor = this.highLightColor;
    }

     @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseOut(eventData : Event){    
      this.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor;     
    }
}
```